# using javascript to add some variables in a php form

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have created a form that retrieves data from a sql database using php . I want to calculate the value for only checked boxes with javascript. This is a little bit of  my php code. what do I have to write in my  javascript function  to select only the products with checked boxes? I find it a little bit difficult because the data is retrieved from a sql database

```
echo '<name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'">';
echo '<name="CalculatedPrice" value="'.$row['Calculated Price'].'">';
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox' name='chooseme'>";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure exactly what you mean but I think something like this should work. First put the cost as a custom attribute (data-cost) in the checkbox:

```
echo '<name="Product" value="'.$row['Product'].'">';
echo '<name="CalculatedPrice" value="'.$row['Calculated Price'].'">';
echo "<input type='checkbox' data-cost='".$row['Calculated Price']."' id='checkbox' name='chooseme'>";
```

Then to get the total cost from all checkboxes that are checked in Javascript (I'm using jQuery) you can do:

```
var totalCost = 0;
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(checkbox) {
    totalCost+=parseInt($(this).attr("data-cost"));
});
```